# MonoTouch. Split information out of Text File

Tags: xamarin.ios

I only work with MonoTouch since few days, and now I have a little problem, so I need help.

In my Main View I create a Text File where different information are given, like "Name,Lastname,Phonenumber"

All these information are splitted by ","

Now I want to work with these information so I have to load the Text file, until here all works fine.

The problem I have, I dont want the whole content of text file in one label.
there should be one label for Name one for Lastname and so on.

I tryed to work with Regex, but dont work.

Hope you understand my question, sry for my bad english ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```cs
string line;
using (var fs = new StreamReader (filename)) {
    while ((line = fs.ReadLine ()) != null) {
        var fields = line.Split (',');
        var name = fields [0];
        var lastname = fields [1];
        var phonenumber = fields [2];
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine ;) Ty a lot. I love the support here ;)